# is the operator $A:C[-3,-1] \rightarrow L_{2}[-2, 0]$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let operator $A:C[-3,-1] \rightarrow L_{2}[-2, 0]$
given by the formula
$$
(Ax)(t) = (t + 2)sgn(3t+3)x(-t-3)
$$
What have I tried?
\begin{multline*}
||Ax||_{L_{2}[-2, 0]} = \left(\int\limits_{-2}^{0}\left|(t + 2)sgn(3t+3)x(-t-3)\right|\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \max\limits_{[-2,0]} x(-t-3)\left(\int\limits_{-2}^{0}\left|(t + 2)sgn(3t+3)\right|\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \\
\left[\max\limits_{[-2,0]} x(-t-3) = \max\limits_{[-3,1]}x(t) = ||x|| \And |sgn(3t+3)| = 1\right] = ||x||\left(\int\limits_{-2}^{0}|t+2|dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = ||x||\sqrt{2}
\end{multline*}
That means that $A$ is bounded

> Are there any ideas how I can show that this operator is bounded?

Comment: what means 'restricted' ??

Comment: bounded or limited

Comment: You forgot to square the function $(Ax)(t)$ before integrating.